# How to handle special charectors in jmeter

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-4.0

In my application one of server value have spacial charector like [[.
Could you please some one let me know how to handle in regular exp
My correlation value is :
"rpc\" : [[\"(.*?)\"

Answer (score 1):

Use \ before for all specal caharecters 
Ex like below

"rpc\" : [[\"(.*?)\"

Answer (score 0):

Your server response seems to be [JSON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) therefore it's not best idea to use Regular Expression Extractor for correlation.

Since [JMeter 3.0](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/5-key-things-you-need-know-about-jmeter-30) you have [JSON Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor) which allows fetching data from JSON responses using [JSONPath](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath) query language, in your case it would be something like `$..rpc` or `$..rpc[0]`

[image]